# Clarification Quotients in Ring Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+1).$ Is the ideal generated by the image of $x+1$ isomorphic to $(2,x+1)/(2,x^3+1) \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)?$

Comment: So you're saying the image of the ideal $(x+1)$ in $\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^3+1)$ is the same as the image of the ideal $(2,x+1)$ in $\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^3+1)$?

Comment: I guess it's true because $2=0$ in $\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^3+1)$

Comment: It seems to me the problem in saying that $(x+1)/(2,x^3+1)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)$ is that $(x+1) \not\subset (2,x^3+1)$.  Which is why I have to talk in terms of $(2,x+1)$.

Comment: Do you mean $(x+1)\not\supseteq(2,x^3+1)$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: It makes sense to talk about $\left(\overline{x+1}\right)$ in $\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^3+1)$.  And $\left(\overline{x+1}\right)=\left(\overline 2,\overline{x+1}\right)$ since $\overline 2=\overline 0$.

Comment: First of all, when I talk about the image of $x+1$ in the original post, I mean the image of $\overline{x+1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)$ under the isomorphism.  Second, we know that all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)$ are of the form $I/(2,x^3+1)$, where $I$ is an ideal containing $(2,x^3+1)$.  Hence I suppose your $(\overline{x+1})$ is just $(2,x+1)/(2,x^3+1)$.  I think I understand now.

Comment: Yes, I think you're totally on top of this problem, I don't see anything wrong with what you wrote.